# Deserialize Json Data in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am getting account information back from iContact and Cannot deserialize into the class.

**Please help deserialize the following data stream:**

```
"{""accounts"":[{""billingStreet"":""3800 Mylanta Drive, 6th Floor"",""billingCity"":""Orlando"",""billingState"":""FL"",""billingPostalCode"":""32789"",""billingCountry"":""United States"",""city"":""Orlando"",""accountId"":""33323"",""companyName"":""My Company"",""country"":""United States"",""email"":""myemail@email.com"",""enabled"":""1"",""fax"":"""",""firstName"":""U.S."",""lastName"":""One &amp;amp;  Two"",""multiClientFolder"":""1"",""multiUser"":""1"",""phone"":""(999) 999-9999"",""postalCode"":""32789"",""state"":""FL"",""street"":""3800 Mylanta Drive, 6th Floor"",""title"":""Marketing "",""accountType"":""0"",""subscriberLimit"":""250000""}],""total"":1,""limit"":20,""offset"":0}"
```

**I am using the following classes**

```
Public Class contactJSONClass
    Public accounts As Account

End Class
Public Class ContactClass
    Public AppId As String
    Public BaseUrl As String
    Public Username As String
    Public Password As String
    Public AccountId As String
    Public ClientFolderId As String
    Public TestMode As Boolean

End Class
Public Class AccountIDClass
    Public AccountID As String
End Class
Public Class Account
    Public billingCity As String
    Public billingCountry As String
    Public billingState As String
    Public billingStreet As String
    Public billingPostalCode As String
    Public city As String
    Public accountId As String
    Public companyName As String
    Public country As String
    Public email As String
    Public enabled As String
    Public fax As String
    Public firstName As String
    Public lastName As String
    Public multiClientFolder As String
    Public multiUser As String
    Public phone As String
    Public postalCode As String
    Public state As String
    Public street As String
    Public title As String
    Public accountType As String
    Public subscriberLimit As String
End Class
```

**And the code to deserialize is:**

```
' API route 
            Dim apiRoute As String = My.Settings.Base_URL & "a/"

            Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = Await client.GetAsync(apiRoute)
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()

            responseBody = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
            'Parse JSON
            model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of contactJSONClass))(responseBody)
```

Here is the string one more time pasted in Plain text from VS Studio
Where responseBody is the variable name and string at the end is the data type

```
responseBody    "{""accounts"":[{""billingStreet"":""3800 Mylanta Drive, 6th Floor"",""billingCity"":""Orlando"",""billingState"":""FL"",""billingPostalCode"":""32789"",""billingCountry"":""United States"",""city"":""Orlando"",""accountId"":""33323"",""companyName"":""My Company"",""country"":""United States"",""email"":""myemail@email.com"",""enabled"":""1"",""fax"":"""",""firstName"":""U.S."",""lastName"":""One &amp;amp; Two"",""multiClientFolder"":""1"",""multiUser"":""1"",""phone"":""(999) 999-9999"",""postalCode"":""32789"",""state"":""FL"",""street"":""3800 Mylanta Drive, 6th Floor"",""title"":""Marketing "",""accountType"":""0"",""subscriberLimit"":""250000""}],""total"":1,""limit"":20,""offset"":0}"    String
```

Comment: And what is the problem?  The JSON posted has a lot of extra quotes; that cant be how you are getting it.

Comment: The problem is that nothing happens. The model comes out empty

Comment: Get the real JSON onto the clipboard and **Edit Menu** -> **Paste Special** -> **Paste Json as Classes**  You have some odd things there for instance `ContactClass` is not used

Comment: Yes contactClass is not used (ignore).  
I cannot copy and paste, the string is too long. So I pasted it at the bottom

Comment: The PASTE JSON AS CLASSES thing is what you do in Visual Studio (not SO) to create valid classes for given JSON.  The JSON posted is not valid (semi colons should not be quoted, for instance).

Comment: I figured something is wrong. Unfortunately I am not the source